# View pager inside View pager swipe conflict

Tags: android-viewpager, android-tablayout

My activity have Main activity with Tab Layout & View Pager,
In View Pager first fragment is having another View Pager  which is inflating Fragment & vertically swipe action. While my main view pager is horizontal in swipe.

Now it is creating problem in horizontal swipe as its event is eaten out by vertical swipe fragment.

any help.
[image]

Comment: Hope this will help you to make multi level tabs with viewpager in android. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261057/android-how-to-build-multiplelevel-tabs/34262629#34262629

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your pager adapter, make sure you use `getChildFragmentManager` like :

```
MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager);
```